# Having a custom QueryStringBindable in the scope with Play 2.4.3

Tags: scala, playframework, query-string, playframework-2.4, querystringparameter

I would like to have java.sql.Date and Option[java.sql.Date] in my Play-scala project as a query-paramater, which don't come as a default with the Play framework. Play-version I'm using is 2.4.3. I have following (rough) class.

```
object CustomBinders extends {
  val dateFormat = ISODateTimeFormat.date()

  implicit def dateBinder: QueryStringBindable[Date] = new QueryStringBindable[Date] {
    def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, Date]] = {
      val dateString: Option[Seq[String]] = params.get(key)
      try {
        Some(Right(new Date(dateFormat.parseDateTime(dateString.get.head).getMillis)))
      } catch {
        case e: IllegalArgumentException => Option(Left(dateString.get.head))
      }
    }

    def unbind(key: String, value: Date): String = {
      dateFormat.print(value.getTime)
    }
  }
}
```

Then in Build.scala I have

```
import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys

object Build extends Build {
  RoutesKeys.routesImport += "binders.CustomBinders.dateBinder"
  RoutesKeys.routesImport += "binders.CustomBinders.optionDateBinder"
```

However if I define a query-parameter with Option[Date] for an example, I'm getting an error

```
No QueryString binder found for type Option[java.sql.Date]. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.
```

So it obviously isn't the scope. How should I define the Binders so that they exist in the scope? I can't find the 2.4-documentation for this, but [2.5-documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders) doesn't say anything about needing to add them to Build.scala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So appereantly the Build.scala wasn't the right place... Even though some documentations tell to put it there. When in build.sbt

```
routesImport += "binders.CustomBinders._"
```

The project compiles just fine. Fixed some faults in the original post for the Binder as well.

Comment: Don't forget to import `import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.{routesImport}`